# Preventing Public Access of an Azure App Service app directory

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently on a free App Service plan and have uploaded a certificate (.pfx file) via FTP to `/site/certs/mycert.pfx`. My app is published to `/site/wwwroot/` which is publicly accessible. I want my app to be able to access the certificates in `/certs/`, but not have `/certs/` publicly accessible to anyone else.

Is that how it is currently working or do I need to do some configuration to block outside access to `/certs/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not necessary** to do additional configuration to block outside access to your files in kudu.

You could have a look at the security of kudu:

> Ones with Kudu access are ones owning the site. To expand, they can
> deploy any codes (good or malicious) to and has access to any secret
> settings of the site (eg. KeyVault, SQL and Storage credentials,
> Private Certificates, etc.). In Azure, only those with Contributor /
> Owner access (to be exact, with microsoft.web/sites/publish/action or,
> for slot, microsoft.web/sites/slots/publish/action) will have access
> to Kudu (SCM).

You could also [Import a certificate in Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-import-certificate), which is the recommended way to store your certificate safely.